# Реализация refresh

Tags: авторизация, oauth, jwt

Изучаю JWT. Понял все про access token, но вот про refresh token информации гуглится куда меньше почему-то. Есть несколько вопросов, безотносительно какого-то конкретного языка или реализации.

---

1. Я так понял он сам может иметь произвольный формат? Как вариант: сконкатенировать также через точку его expirationTime, рандомную строку и часть или целиком сигнатуру access token. И обернуть в base64urlencode. Вообще нормально ли добавлять туда целиком сигнатуру или это небезопасно? Можно с конца сигнатуры несколько символов взять. Просто встречал описание такой реализации.

У меня вот тут есть задача и в ней описание:

`Refresh токен тип произвольный, формат передачи base64, хранится в базе исключительно в виде bcrypt хеша, должен быть защищен от изменения на стороне клиента и попыток повторного использования.`

Я не понял последнюю фразу, начиная с "должен быть".

---

2. Как именно должна выглядеть операция refresh? Как я понял: получаем пару access и refresh токенов, парсим их, валидируем access token (сравниваем сигнатуры). Дальше пошли непонятки.

2.2. Надо ли проверять expirationTime у access token? В принципе для этого метода мне кажется все равно истек он или нет - главное чтобы refresh token не истек.

2.3. Дальше наверное логично проверить expirationTime у распарсенного refresh token? Не истек ли он.

2.4. Если не истек, то, если я правильно понял, мы берем userId, полученный из распарсенного access token (поле iss в payload) и ищем по нему refresh token в базе. После чего сравниваем refresh токены и если они равны генерируем новую пару токенов, заменяем старый refresh token в базе и отдаем их клиенту.

Опять же по задаче есть такая формулировка:

`Access, Refresh токены обоюдно связаны, Refresh операцию для Access токена можно выполнить только тем Refresh токеном который был выдан вместе с ним`

Насколько я понимаю это обеспечивается просто тем что сравнивается токен из базы и потом заменяется в ней?

---

Все правильно или нет?

Comment: Вы путаете JWT и OAuth. Понятия "access token" и "refresh token" относятся именно к OAuth, и JWT тут совершенно ни при чём (можно JWT вообще не использовать)

Comment: @andreymal на хабре так написано: [access_token](https://habr.com/ru/post/340146/), [refresh_token](https://habr.com/ru/post/466929/).

Comment: В этой статье про access token и refresh токен ничего не написано. И в общем-то не должно быть написано, потому что они не имеют никакого отношения к JWT

Comment: @andreymal рядом еще вторая ссылка, на статью по refresh token

Comment: А в ней для refresh token используется вообще не JWT. Потому что JWT для рефреш-токена нафиг не нужен :)

Comment: @andreymal [вот еще статья](https://vc.ru/dev/106534-jwt-kak-bezopasnyy-sposob-autentifikacii-i-peredachi-dannyh). Тут про оба токена.

Comment: Ну так вы сами-то эту статью прочитайте, там так и написано: "это может быть некая случайная строка" - никакой JWT здесь не нужен.

Comment: @andreymal да я и не спорю. Я просто про саму технологию авторизации спрашиваю. Можете ответить по вопросам в посте?

Comment: Про саму технологию я уже написал в самом первом комментарии - вы путаете с OAuth. Читайте статьи про OAuth, и не зацикливайтесь на JWT. JWT - это всего лишь один из возможных форматов хранения данных, и никто не заставляет использовать для токенов именно JWT, можно взять любой другой формат или изобрести свой.

Comment: @andreymal да господи, зачем вы придираетесь к словам??? Ну перепутал я понятия. Вы ответьте по вопросам в посте лучше, а не спорьте.